# Docker não está rodando

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, contains

Boa noite, galera

Instalei o docker e criei alguns container, meu computador travou e depois de reinicia-lo ao tentar executar o comando docker retorna a mensagem: Is docker daemon running on this host?

Na internet achei comandos de start apenas para os container, mas não acho para o docker. Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: A documentação do link irá te ajudar | https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/

Comment: Pode incluir na pergunta a saída do comando `uname -a`? Assim é mais fácil de ajudar, pois saberemos qual versão do ubuntu está sendo executada. Seja systemd, seja SystemV ou Upstart (cada um deles gerencia processos de uma forma diferente).

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa adicionar o seu usuário ao grupo `docker`:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

depois faça logout/login de novo e você deve ter acesso.